# What is -1 & -2 shown by IntelliJ Debugger in an UTF8 string and how to remove it?

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, utf-8

When parsing my string from a file on Windows 10 I kinda have two characters that are not removable by whitespaces trims and such.

[image]

Here is evidence of the culprit.

This somewhat screws up my regex `^(\w+)` because it happens that there is a whitespace in it.
When I copy the value of the string (screenshot) into RegExr for example I see there is a whitespace added - and that is why my regex will net work.

[image]

I already googled for `-1 -2 in UTF-8 string` but was not able to find anything and therefore am super confused with that.

Comment: These screenshots are useless unless you're okay with a wild goose chase. Copy+paste the problematic string into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your debugger is being silly for showing them as -1 and -2 respectively, but it's clear enough that you're dealing with the [UTF-16 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16) (not UTF-8 as you claim in the question, that one is a 3-byte marker that's completely different).

Feel free to check for their presence and remove them if you encounter them at the beginning of a file, though ideally you should save your file without the BOM in the first place.

Comment: So it's either `254 255` or `255 254` to check for I assume?

Comment: Yeah, depending on your system's endianness.